# Flask SocketIO timeout when using web server instead of localhost

Tags: docker, sockets, nginx, gunicorn, flask-socketio

I am working on a basic web messaging app with Flask, that I am deploying using docker with gunicorn as the wsgi and nginx for my proxy server. Everything works on localhost when I run the containers, but I get an error when I am trying to send messages via sockets to my remote server, running the same container constellation. More specifically, I am told that the socket timed out. This is strange because all non-socket interactions are very quick, while not actually being more computationally intensiv (message are sent almost instantly when working locally).

Socket framework I am using is Flask-SocketIO and I am processing messages using eventlet. My function for receiving and emitting when a user sends a message is done with the following code:

```
@socketio.on('post message')
def add_new_msg(data):
    data['isPending'] = False
    if len(data['message']) <= 0:
        return
    sql_query = 'INSERT INTO messages (chatroomid, messagecontent, timestamp, sendername) '
    sql_query += 'SELECT :chatroomid, :messagecontent, :timestamp, :sendername '
    sql_query += 'WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM chatrooms WHERE chatroomid = :chatroomid)'
    row_count = db.execute(sql_query, {
                'chatroomid': data['roomId'],
                'messagecontent': data['message'],
                'timestamp': data['timestamp'],
                'sendername': data['username']
                }).rowcount
    db.commit()
    if row_count > 0:
        emit('server message callback', data, broadcast=True)
```

thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**EDIT:**
Added the error log.

```
app_1         | [2019-06-16 13:53:59 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
app_1         | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 66, in handle
app_1         |     six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/six.py", line 625, in reraise
app_1         |     raise value
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 56, in handle
app_1         |     self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 129, in handle_request
app_1         |     six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/six.py", line 625, in reraise
app_1         |     raise value
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 107, in handle_request
app_1         |     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
app_1         |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 44, in __call__
app_1         |     start_response)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/middleware.py", line 59, in __call__
app_1         |     return self.engineio_app.handle_request(environ, start_response)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 428, in handle_request
app_1         |     return self.eio.handle_request(environ, start_response)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/server.py", line 340, in handle_request
app_1         |     environ, start_response)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 106, in handle_get_request
app_1         |     start_response)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 146, in _upgrade_websocket
app_1         |     return ws(environ, start_response)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/async_drivers/eventlet.py", line 20, in __call__
app_1         |     return super(WebSocketWSGI, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 130, in __call__
app_1         |     self.handler(ws)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 160, in _websocket_handler
app_1         |     pkt = ws.wait()
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 788, in wait
app_1         |     for i in self.iterator:
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 643, in _iter_frames
app_1         |     message = self._recv_frame(message=fragmented_message)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 669, in _recv_frame
app_1         |     header = recv(2)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 578, in _get_bytes
app_1         |     d = self.socket.recv(numbytes - len(data))
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 366, in recv
app_1         |     return self._recv_loop(self.fd.recv, b'', bufsize, flags)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 360, in _recv_loop
app_1         |     self._read_trampoline()
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 331, in _read_trampoline
app_1         |     timeout_exc=socket_timeout('timed out'))
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 210, in _trampoline
app_1         |     mark_as_closed=self._mark_as_closed)
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 159, in trampoline
app_1         |     return hub.switch()
app_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 298, in switch
app_1         |     return self.greenlet.switch()
app_1         | socket.timeout: timed out
```

Comment: Can you add a complete copy of the error please?

Comment: Thanks for your response - I added it to the question.

Comment: Did you monkey patch the standard library? See https://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html for information on this.

Comment: How would I call the monkeypatch with Gunicorn? Or do I do it in a separate container by running the patch via a script (does it permanently affect the STL)?

Comment: Gunicorn monkey patches by default, but this hasn't worked well at times, so it depends on what version of Gunicorn you are using I guess. It's best to also monkey patch in your code. This isn't permanent, see the link I gave, everything is explained there.

Comment: Tried different Gunicorn versions, none that worked for me - any other suggestions, assuming that Gunicorn already does the monkeypatching?

Comment: Eventlet is very sensitive to blocking. If you are monkey patched, then something that you are doing in your application is blocking and falls outside of the things that eventlet monkey patches. Think about any unusual things you do in your application.

Comment: I have thought about this a lot and I am honestly not sure. The only code that is socket related can be seen as part of the post, it does not seem that strange to me. Is there any way that other calls can block the socket?

Comment: It's not limited to socket operations, anything that you do in your application that is somewhat CPU intensive will block eventlet from operating normally.

Answer (score 0):

Well - I feel a bit silly for this. Upon giving up and then trying to show someone the bug at work, I found out that the app was working perfectly. It was then that I realised that the wifi at my house must have somehow prevented the server from sending back the socket response. So it was really working - thanks Miguel for sticking with me!